# Recycling bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

I want to write code to load an image from the internet.
I load a picture into my app and `setImageBitmap(Bitmap)` in my `ImageView`. But if I write

```
if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled())
{
    bitmap.recycle();
}
```

The `ImageView` will not show, otherwise it will show. Can you tell me why? 
For example:

```
private void downloadPost()
{
    HttpURLConnection conn = null;
    try
    {
        URL url = new URL(IMAGE_URL);
        conn = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        if (conn.getResponseCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK)
        {
            InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            Message msg = new Message();
            msg.obj = bitmap;
            msg.what = 1;
            handler.sendMessage(msg);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void handleMessage(Message msg)
{
    super.handleMessage(msg);
    switch (msg.what)
    {
        case 1:
            Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) msg.obj;
            imageview.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            if (bitmap != null && !bitmap.isRecycled())
            {
                bitmap.recycle();
            }
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: If you recycle it it's gone, isn't it?

Answer (score 0):

`Bitmap.recycle()` is not something you really need to call unless you are loading lots of images. It is only there for the cases where you need to optimise things to be more memory efficient. Simply remove the call to `recycle()` and you'll be fine.

Check the documentation for more details: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#recycle()

> This is an advanced call, and normally need not be called, since the normal GC process will free up this memory when there are no more references to this bitmap

Answer (score 0):

I am completely agree with Erik Hellman's solution, but as I have seen your code above , you are still using very traditional behavior for image loading. Just for increasing your knowledge, I would suggest to use [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/)
.It will automatically handle all image loading scenarios like: automatic image caching and handling OutOfMemoryException. It's very easy to use Picasso you will find working example [here](http://javatechig.com/android/opensource/how-to-use-picasso-library-in-android)

Answer (score -1):

```
bitmap.recycle();
```

Will free memory from bitmap. Here when you are doing bitmap.recycle() it will clear bitmap memory so because of this image is not showing.

Comment: This is not exactly correct. `recycle()` will only mark the image data as "dead", so that no more operations (like callikng `getPixels()`) can be made on this object. The freeing of memory happens asynchronously at a later point.